# Wiki with link autocompletion?

Tags: wiki, autocomplete

I'm looking for a wiki with the follow features:

- simple WYSIWYG editor (actually, it'd be perfect if the WYSIWYG editor is the default way to view a page)
- I need to upload a lot of heavy images, so every time I add an image the wiki should create a compressed version of the image (the compressed version is the displayed in the page, but this compressed image it is linked somewhat to the original one)
- autocompletion for locals links

Note that it does not matter whether it is a desktop app or web-based, monouser or multiuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) can do all of this with a bit of tweaking:

- Uploaded images get displayed as dynamically-generated thumbnails
- WYSIWYG thanks to the [Visual Editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor) extension
- The Visual Editor includes auto-completion of local wikilinks. Start start typing and possible choices appear.

It is web-based.